# About set id=1 and password = ' ' in the SQL injection

Tags: php, mysql, sql, linux, sql-injection

Here is certain expert's code:

https://github.com/DalerAsrorov/Security-Flaws-And-Their-Prevention/blob/master/SQL%20Injection%20Prevention/FCCU.php#L34

In this example, at first line 34 and 35 doesn't exist. So, it have one bug as described here:

https://github.com/DalerAsrorov/Security-Flaws-And-Their-Prevention/blob/master/SQL%20Injection%20Prevention/exploit3.txt#L21-L24

Set id and password as:

> i)' OR '1'='1
>      ii)' OR ''='
>      iii) hi' OR 'x'='x

Which also mentioned here:

https://github.com/nathanctung/UCLA-CS-136/blob/1a883e2a6d1014fb5b162b332c867f6b4ef1e461/Assignment%203/submit3-1415097322/exploit3.txt#L21-L25

I am a noob in SQL and php. Really don't know why is this. I'd appreciate if you can tell me.

Update:

In this case, I should have input username and password to log in. But this bug enable one to input something else to log in and see some private content which only accessible to certain group. And the 34 and 35 line fix this bug. I don't know really understand this bug, why some other input enable you to log in?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to ask here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: @Darren I add something else. I'd appreciate if you can help me to fix topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP, if you want to verify if `user_id` and `password` is correct (notice that this program use `user_id`, instead of `username`), usually you write the query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = <input_id> AND password = <input_password>
```

Then, you check if the query returns empty row, then it is invalid user. If the query returns 1 row, then the username and password is correct.

Now, if I want to login as other user (the other user's id is `1` in this case), I will insert `1` in the `id` column. However, I dont know the password. So, I must find a way to make these part in the query always return true `password = <input_password>`

One way to do that is by using `password = 'random_string' OR password != ''`. As the password always more than 0 character, the latter logical expression will always return `true`. So, I want the query to be something like this

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = 1 AND password = '<random_string>' OR password != ''
```

Therefore, I will insert `1` in the id, and `test' OR password != '` to make the query like above.

This query will never return empty row as long as `user_id` with value `1` exists, and you can login as user `1` in the application.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you're asking for how this works?

Well- if you logically check `password='secret'` you get `true` and are thus allowed to enter. `password='dunno'` should and will get you `false` and keep you from entering.

But logically `password='whatever' OR true` will get you `true` again. Just that you have a syntax error without dealing with the apostrophe. So the above versions deal with them - but essentially they achieve the same.